# How do I set a scatterplot's marker colour based on a text field?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, scatter

I have a 2d python list where each row has a x, y, z value, but my z value is text which only consists of one of two values, either 'br' or 'comp'

I'd like to make a scatterplot which uses the x,y values and then shows the z value as a colour based on the text. Here is an idea of what my array looks like:

```
| x     | y     | z     |

|---    |-----  |------ |

| 1     | 1.2   | br    |

| 2     | 4.3   | comp  |

| 3     | 4.5   | comp  |

| 4     | 6.7   | br    |
```

I tried to see if it would recognize and just make two separate classes based on the field value, but alas, I get a ValueError:

`ValueError: 'c' argument must be a mpl color, a sequence of mpl colors or a sequence of numbers, not ['br', 'comp', etc]`

Here is what my plotting code looks like:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols = 2, sharex = True, sharey = True, figsize = (20,20))
axs = axs.flatten()
for j in range(len(devs)):
    axs[j].scatter([i[2] for i in devs[j]], [i[4] for i in devs[j]], c = [i[3] for i in devs[j]])
plt.show()
```

`devs` is a list of 2d python lists. my x values are in the third column, y values in the 5th, and the z values are in my 4th column, hence the complex scatterplot line of code.

My expected results are an x,y scatterplot with two different coloured markers, one colour corresponding to rows with the z value "comp" and the other colour to the rows with the z value "br".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to hold the colour names. Try the following code and see weather it works.

```
dic =  {
  "br": "red",
  "comp": "green"
}

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols = 2, sharex = True, sharey = True, figsize = (20,20))
axs = axs.flatten()
for j in range(5):
    axs[j].scatter([i[2] for i in devs[j]], [i[4] for i in devs[j]], c = [dic[str(i[3])] for i in devs[j]])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by instead assigning a value to the text when I actually build the list earlier in my code. But @avin's solution should also work!

Something like:

```
if column_value == 'br':
                devs[k][i][3] = 1
            else:
                devs[k][i][3] = 0
```